How to create a mapped type for a narrowed union type
I am generating TypeScript code for my GraphQL schema using a library. Since I am using union types in the GraphQL schema, the generated TS contains unions as well:
 type CreativeWork = {
    typename: 'Book'
    name: string
    pages: number
 } | 
 {
    typename: 'Article'
    name: string
    year: number
    journal: string
 } |
 {
    typename: 'Dataset'
    name: string
    downloads: string[]
 }

This means that the result is either a book, an article, or a dataset.
TS can narrow it down by using typename as a discriminator:
if (a.typename === 'Article') {
    // it's an article
    const journal = a.journal
}


How can I create a mapped type that represents the narrowed type, e.g., "Article"?

What, specifically, is your question? It seems like maybe "I don't understand what this does" is the question; you'd like an explanation? But then you say "also I am wondering" and ask a separate question about how to compute 'Article' | 'Book' | 'Dataset' from CreativeWork. Please [edit] to make clear what your single primary question is (if you leave it so it looks like multiple questions, it might get closed as needing focus). Personally with your use case I'd just use Extract as shown here, but I can't tell which part of that, if any, answers the question.

No problem, I edited my question. Your answer is great. I think the approach I took was unnecessarily cumbersome, however, I would still like to understand what it actually does.

I mean, it's a strange approach; all you've done is make a mapped type and then index into it, which is mostly a no-op because you never reference the iterated type parameter P anywhere. All this does is have the effect of distributing over T because it's a homomorphic mapped type. Let's assume T is not a union. Then {[P in keyof T]: F<T>}[keyof T]} is just going to be F<T>. I'm confused why you're asking what the indexed access does and not what the mapped type does. Not sure how to proceed.

(see prev comment) The title "Create new type for narrowed union type" makes it sound like a reasonable question, "how should I write this". But then when you read the question it sounds more like "Trial and error brought me this solution which works, but I don't understand it. Here's one little piece of it, how does that work?" Which is... well I'd have to explain the whole thing and it's not the way one should generally approach this. It's more like... forensics? I could write out an explanation but I'm not sure it's helpful to future readers.

I think the "the effect of distributing over T" explains what I get without applying [keyof T]  and answers "What does the expression without the [keyof T] produce", thank you very much.

"which is mostly a no-op because you never reference the iterated type parameter P anywhere." Actually, I did in my first attempt but it seemed pointless to me since typename is the only property which could have this type. Hence, the whole iteration is pointless, like you say yourself, and this is why Extract is the apt solution for this. If you think it would still be worth to improve the question I will gladly do so. To make this more general: Is there a 1:1 relation between narrowing and extracting a type via mapped types? Would that be more adequate?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

(I won't go into the chat; these are clarifications on the question and belong here.) I do recommend you [edit] the question to clearly ask a single well-defined question that is reflected both in the title and the body. Right now the title implies one thing, and the question body has two questions. You should pick one and ask it clearly and succinctly. Ideally you'd ask "how do I do this" and remove your attempt and the questions about why it happens to work, so that way someone can answer with Extract, which is really the only thing helpful to future readers. But it's up to you.

I strongly suspect the answer you accepted is AI generated.
